OpenTelemetry X-Ray: Traces without hierarchy
I've configured opentelemetry on my lambdas using ADOT OpenTelemetry AWS distribution.
I mean, I'm using javaagent + collector layer attached to my lambdas, following this documentation.
That means that I'm using openTelemetry agent + collector and I'm autoinstrumention my code using agent.
After that, my traces are generated, but not aligned on X-Ray console.
I mean, opentelemetry agent is instrumenting my mongo and S3 access. Lambda traces are also generated.
So, I'm getting traces for:

lambda context executation traces
S3 access traces
mongodb access traces

However, traces appear not related between them:

I don't quite figure out how to create relation between them in order to putt all it together.
I've took a look on logs. Following traces are generated:
[otel.javaagent 2024-04-24 07:59:05:633 +0000] [main] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - 'update espaidoc.document' : 6628bbc902c4d22192672fe5958a00cd eb8b0f340609ba59 CLIENT [tracer: io.opentelemetry.mongo-3.1:1.32.0-adot-lambda1-alpha] AttributesMap{data={db.operation=update, db.mongodb.collection=document, db.name=espaidoc, thread.id=1, thread.name=main, db.connection_string=mongodb://pe-0-endurance-mongodb-dev-cluster.r6c5pur.mongodb.net:27017, net.peer.name=pe-0-endurance-mongodb-dev-cluster.r6c5pur.mongodb.net, db.system=mongodb, net.peer.port=27017, db.statement={\"update\": \"document\", \"ordered\": \"?\", \"writeConcern\": {\"w\": \"?\"}, \"txnNumber\": \"?\", \"$db\": \"?\", \"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": \"?\", \"signature\": {\"hash\": \"?\", \"keyId\": \"?\"}}, \"lsid\": {\"id\": \"?\"}, \"updates\": [{\"q\": {\"_id\": \"?\"}, \"u\": {\"_id\": \"?\", \"logicId\": \"?\", \"location\": {\"location\": \"?\", \"type\": \"?\"}, \"status\": {\"state\": \"?\"}, \"md5Checksum\": \"?\", \"_class\": \"?\"}, \"upsert\": \"?\"}]}}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=10}
[otel.javaagent 2024-04-24 07:59:05:620 +0000] [main] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - 'S3.HeadObject' : 6628bbc95db57510853694261956a4d1 4c10b44d043a4612 CLIENT [tracer: io.opentelemetry.aws-sdk-2.2:1.32.0-adot-lambda1-alpha] AttributesMap{data={aws.agent=java-aws-sdk, http.method=HEAD, aws.requestId=1Y3J5K61D9ZHSV5X, net.peer.name=s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, rpc.method=HeadObject, net.peer.port=443, http.url=https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/espaidoc-des/frontoffice-apigateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar, rpc.system=aws-api, thread.id=1, thread.name=main, http.status_code=200, aws.bucket.name=espaidoc-des, http.response_content_length=50984457, rpc.service=S3}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=14}
XRAY TraceId: 1-6628bbc9-0439f53a54534f10181c6da0\tSegmentId: 0111f4aa09e348cc\tSampled: true

Any ideas?

Is it the same problem as https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-lambda/issues/781 ?

I think so. I'm using java 17 and I'm getting same behavior. It's not clear to what's the suggested workaround. It's clear for you?

The latest ADOT Java Lambda layer has supported Lambda java17 Runtime, could you update your layer ARN to the the latest? arn:aws:lambda::901920570463:layer:aws-otel-java-agent--ver-1-31-0:1

It's strange. Some months ago I was playing with 1-32 layer version. Where do you see a new layer version was published solving java 17 issue?
